# Create a ArrayList of byte Array in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, arrays, byte

I want to read bytes from httpresponse coming from server continuosly into an array.

I'm creating a byte array with a maximum size of 2048.

So, I wanted to create a dynamically increasing array and I found that ArrayList is the solution.

How can i overcome this solution?

Any help would be appreciated lot

Comment: yes..actually i want this for  audio record and play the same through http request and response... so while recording in one second its listening about 20 times but while playing its able to receive only 2 to 5 bytes of data out of 20 so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can have an array of byte like:**

`List<Byte> arrays = new ArrayList<Byte>();`

**To convert it back to arrays**

`Byte[] soundBytes = arrays.toArray(new Byte[arrays.size()]);`

**-** You can also use `ByteArrayInputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

**Eg:**

```
InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();  

// read from the stream  
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
byte[] content = new byte[ 2048 ];  
int bytesRead = -1;  
while( ( bytesRead = inputStream.read( content ) ) != -1 ) {  
    baos.write( content, 0, bytesRead );  
} // while  

// now, as you have baos in hand, I don't think you still need a bais instance  
// but, to make it complete,
// now you can generate byte array input stream as below    
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream( baos.toByteArray() );
```

Comment: @GMRamesh That will work in Android as well. However, as I indicate in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13466932/535871), using `ArrayList<Byte>` is a very expensive solution.

Comment: @GMRamesh First of all the solution i gave works on `both java and android`, and yes I have EDITED my answer..pls see it

Comment: hi vivek,, check the following link and tell me if u know the solution for this.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469835/store-live-recording-voice-in-a-queuebyte-and-send-it-to-the-server

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) to accumulate the bytes as you read them from the server. I would not use an `ArrayList<Byte>` because it requires boxing every byte value in a `Byte`.

When you want to access the bytes that have been accumulated, just call `toByteArray()` on the `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: hi tedd, i also want to send recorded data to be in arraylist and send it across to the server...how can i do this? .. I have to do same like above for send also

Comment: @GMRamesh - Your recorded data is in an `ArrayList<Byte>`? See if you can capture it in a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead.

Comment: no recorded data is not in ArrayList<Byte>.... i m sending that recorded byte array directly to server thats y i m missing some of bytes while sending to server

Comment: As i m reading the data  continuosly in a thread and sending the same data at same time ...its missing some of the byte values

Comment: i m using JSON to send byte array to the server

Comment: @GMRamesh - It sounds like you need a buffer queue of some sort so that as you record, you place buffers full of bytes into the queue and to transmit to the server, you take the next buffer from the queue. That way things will only get lost if the queue overflows. (If you simply can't send to the server as fast as you record, then if you record long enough, this is bound to happen.)

Comment: yeah exactly... even i tried that to put in a queue also but still its missing data "Queue<byte[]> qArray = new LinkedList<byte[]>();
qArray.add(bData[count]);" like this i have done but still no use... please tell me any other solution for this

Comment: @GMRamesh - I suggest you open a separate question about why your queue solution doesn't work. Post the code you are using along with a description of what you want it to do and what's going wrong. The conversation has strayed enough the original question that a fresh start would be more productive.

Comment: hi ted... check the following link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469835/store-live-recording-voice-in-a-queuebyte-and-send-it-to-the-server