# record voice in a Queue<byte[]> and send it to the server

Tags: java, android, linked-list, arrays, bytebuffer

I am developing voice application.

I need a buffer queue of some sort so that i record continuosly in a thread , place the buffers full of bytes into the queue and to transmit to the server, and i take the next buffer from the queue.

Here is the recording code:

```
     Queue<byte[]> qArray = new LinkedList<byte[]>();
     recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            bData = new byte[BufferElements];

            while (isRecording) {
                recorder.read(bData, 0, BufferElements);
                qArray.add(bData);
                if (AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != 0) {
                    SendAudio();

                }

            }
        }
    }, "AudioRecorder Thread");
    recordingThread.start();
```

**But still its missing few of byte[] data while sending it to the server**

Here is the sending voice to the server code:

```
           try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(ServerUrl.url_audio);

            // Json Format
            JSONObject holder = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
            try {

                byte[] tmparr = qArray.poll();
                for (int i = 0; i < tmparr.length; i++) {
                    jArray.put(i, tmparr[i]);
                }

                holder.put("Voice", jArray);
```

I dont want to miss any data which is recording.

Any help would be appreciated lot. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you place a byte[] into the queue, you need to then create a new buffer. Otherwise the next recording will overwrite the same buffer. Just move the initialization of `bData` into the loop:

```
Queue<byte[]> qArray = new LinkedList<byte[]>();
recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (isRecording) {
            bData = new byte[BufferElements];
            recorder.read(bData, 0, BufferElements);
            qArray.add(bData);
            if (AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != 0) {
                SendAudio();
            }
        }
    }
}, "AudioRecorder Thread");
recordingThread.start();
```

You should also add logic to limit the size of the queue. If the queue overflows, you will still lose data, but at least you won't crash with an out-of-memory error.

**EDIT** Here's a modified version of the recording loop that does proper error checking. It uses a `Queue<ByteBuffer>` instead of a `Queue<byte[]>`:

```
public void run() {
    bData = ByteBuffer.allocate(BufferElements);
    while (isRecording && !isInterrupted()) {
        int result = recorder.read(bData, 0, BufferElements);
        if (result > 0) {
            qArray.add(bData);
            SendAudio();
            bData = ByteBuffer.allocate(BufferElements);
        } else if (result == AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION) {
            Log.e("Recording", "Invalid operation error");
            break;
        } else if (result == AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
            Log.e("Recording", "Bad value error");
            break;
        } else if (result == AudioRecord.ERROR) {
            Log.e("Recording", "Unknown error");
            break;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, somewhere you'll need to call `recorder.startRecording()` or you won't get any data.

Comment: its not working while sending audio data...its sending all null values to server if i move that in while loop

Comment: @GMRamesh - If you debug, are the arrays being retrieved from the queue all null values?

Comment: @GMRamesh - Is `qArray.poll()` returning `null` or is it returning an array of 0 values? If it is returning `null`, that means that no buffers are being added to it. If the polling is operating on a separate thread from the recording, you may need to provide some synchronization to see the values. Also be sure that the two pieces of code are accessing the same queue instance.

Comment: It is returning only an array of 0 values....these two pieces of code is accessing same queue instance only

Comment: @GMRamesh - Okay, I think the problem is in the recording loop. `recorder.read(...)` does not necessarily read any data at all. You should probably rewrite that loop to pause for a short while (e.g., 50ms) between calls to `read`. It should also not queue the buffer until the buffer has data. Also, since the buffer may not be full, you probably need to use a data structure that maintains a count of the number of bytes. A `ByteBuffer` comes to mind as a good candidate. You can stuff bytes into it in the read loop and when it gets full enough, queue it for transmission and start another one.

Comment: @GMRamesh - I added a new version of the recording loop. It's probably still not 100% right, but it should be an improvement.

Comment: it worked, thanks its sending all the data to the server one by one